# Passing a variable to timer_tick

Tags: c#, timer

Got a problem at the moment, I'm using a timer to do animations and I want to be able to decide where to start using Start and Stop integers as i'll show below.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AnimateKey(0,100); 
}

private void AnimateKey(int Start, int Stop)
{
    myTimer.Interval = 5;
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (myTimer)
    {
        int StartingFrame = Start;
        int StopFrame = Stop;
        etc...etc..
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I want to pass the values 0 and 100 to the Timer Tick event but I have no idea on how to go about doing it.
How can I get the Integers 0 and 100 from the button click to the timer tick ?

Comment: store info in myTimer.Tag

Comment: @DrKoch I'm not aware of a way to put multiple values into the Tag. Also is this a secure way of doing it?

Comment: see my answer for a more complete example

Comment: Side note: 'myTimer.Enabled = true;' and 'myTimer.Start();' perform the same task.  The latter is simply more visually pleasing and makes for better code readability.  Likewise is true of 'myTimer.Enabled = false;' and 'myTimer.Stop();'

Comment: @OhBeWise Oh thanks yea i'm new to C# let alone timers so when it wasn't working i just put in stuff to make it work, didn't notice this wasn't required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a lambda when defining the tick event handler to close over the parameters you need:

```
private void AnimateKey(int Start, int Stop)
{
    myTimer.Interval = 5;
    myTimer.Tick += (s, args) => myTimer_Tick(Start, Stop);
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void myTimer_Tick(int Start, int Stop)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Also note that the `Tick` event of the `Timer` that you're using will be fired in the UI thread, so there is no need for a `lock`; the code is already synchronized.

Comment: Really simple and clean, nice way to solve it with 0 extra code. Also easy to implement elsewhere :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use a class with all info:

```
public class TimerInfo
{
     public int Start;
     public int Stop;
}
```

store an instance in timer's Tag

```
myTimer.Tag = new TimerInfo { Start = 0, Stop = 100 };
```

inside the eventhandler you access this info

```
myTimer = (Timer)sender;
TimerInfo ti = (TimerInfo)myTimer.Tag;
```

Comment: I've been told that Solution 1 is really unsafe, not sure why but i've been told not to use it. And even though the .Tag solution works i'm using it for other stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat hard to understand what you mean, but let's give it a try.
If you ment you want to pass the integers start and stop to the function TimerTick, you probably dont understand the EventArgs parameter. EventArgs is ment to store the arguements which are relevant to your scenario - and the solution is simple.

```
class myTimerEventArgs:EventArgs // Declaring your own event arguements which you want to send
{
 public int start{get;set;} 
 public int stop {get;set;}
 /*Constructor, etc...*/
}
...
//Making the call inside another class:
myTimer_Tick(this,new myTimerEventArgs(0,100);
```

However, I could be misunderstanding you; If are talking about counting the ticks until it reaches 100 ticks (/intervals), the solution is a simple function added to the event, which would probably look like this:

```
int Count = 0;
...
private void Counter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Count++;
}
...
private void AnimateKey(int Start, int Stop)
 {
     myTimer.Interval = 5;
     myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);
     myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Counter);
     myTimer.Enabled = true;
     myTimer.Start();
     while(Count!=100);
     myTimer.Stop();
 }
```

Hope I helped, have a nice day :)

Comment: Btw, Koch's solution is good too, I just dont like the use of Timer.Tag for this purpouse ( Requires implementation of tag, and prevents other uses tag could be used for )

Comment: Not quiet what i meant, sorry if i was a bit vague. I think the previous EventArgs solution you had might work though even though i have no idea what to do with EventArgs, looking up tutorials but still clueless. What I basically want is to be able to access the Integers Start and Stop which i define in Button1_click, and access them in the myTimer_Tick.

Comment: If you can send them to the function, then it might work. That's eventargs' purpose - read up here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9355/Creating-advanced-C-custom-events

if you want me to implement a specific action, just detail what exacly you want to see, and i will edit the answer with a code sample.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look but seeing that it's quiet advanced and a lot of code think it might be a bit too advanced for the simple thing i'm trying.

Comment: I honestly do not think it is. Please tell me an example of an action you want me to implement (what will the tick do) - I will edit it so you'll see the thing working.

Comment: I'm using it to animate gifs, using graphics and select frame on each tick it will display the next frame at a 30ms interval. Start and stop indicate at which frame it will start and stop.